# Lucene search result

Tags: lucene

I have a below data index in lucene 4.8 and code.

```
Finance expense
Admin expenses
Transaction expense
Salary expenses
```

indexing:

```
   try {
    writer = createWriter(ramDirectory);
    for(String line : readFile(FILE_PATH)) {
        String[] split = line.split(",");
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new TextField("id", split[0].trim(), Field.Store.YES));
        doc.add(new TextField("name", split[1].trim(), Field.Store.YES));                                       
        writer.addDocument(doc);                
    }
    writer.commit();            
} finally {
    if(writer != null) {
        writer.close(); 
    }
}
```

search

```
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(ramDirectory));
QueryParser nameQParser = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_48, "name", new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_48));
Query query = nameQParser.parse("expense");
TopDocs queryResults = searcher.search(query, 10);
```

Above code return only below two result. It does not return result which has 's' in it at the end.

Current outcome:

```
Finance expense
Transaction expense
```

Expected outcome:

```
Finance expense
Admin expenses
Transaction expense
Salary expenses
```

Please suggest what is wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use  [WildCardQuery](http://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/WildcardQuery.html), because the word `expense` contains in all four document so you can pass search string as `*expense*` which will return all documents having expense in `name` field. 
 Don't forget to set up `QueryParser` to allow leading wildcards with the following:

```
QueryParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true)
```

Make following changes in your code:

```
nameQParser.setAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
Query query = nameQParser.parse("*expense*");
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the best way to deal with plurals is to use an analyzer that handles them better.  `EnglishAnalyzer` includes a stemmer that should handle that.  It would reduce both "expense" and "expenses" (and "expensed", and "expensing") to the stem "expens" in the index.

Anternately, somewhat clunkier, but you could just use a prefix query in this case:  `Query query = nameQParser.parse("expense*");`